# Copy the first character of a column and replace an existing column with it, while maintaining the spacing as needed

Tags: linux, unix, awk, text, sed

I have a long file that looks like this:

`ATOM     55  CE1 LIG X   1      -2.921   4.159 -10.046  1.00  0.00      LIGA`

I need to take the first letter of the third column, in this case C (but it changes by line), and replace my last column, LIGA, with this character. I need to do this while ensuring the spacing between my 12th and 13th columns is 11, as shown below. I need it to be identical to the line below for my program to understand it.

`ATOM     55  CE1 LIG X   1      -4.950   9.318   4.387  1.00  0.00           C`

I managed to copy the first letter of the third column into a different file, then delete the 13th column from the original file, and paste the different file into the original file with the lines below. However, I can find a way to fix the spacing.

```
cut -c 14 original.pdb > different.pdb
perl -pi -e 's/LIGA//g' original.pdb
paste original.pdb different.pdb >> joint.pdb
mv joint.pdb original.pdb
```

I know awk may work here. I haven't been able to achieve it. I appreciate the help!

Comment: I think output you shown should be `ATOM     55  CE1 LIG X   1      -2.921   4.159 -10.046  1.00  0.00      C`? Is that correct.

Comment: Regarding `I need it to be identical to the line below` - your line below has different values from the input in some fields (e.g. the 7th field has changed from -2.921 to -4.950) and different spacing before the last field (what looks like 6 blanks before `LIGA` has become 11 blanks before `C`) but you said you want to maintain the spacing. So - please [edit] your question to better explain how the input you posted maps to the output you posted as it's not clear which changes from input to output are deliberate and which are mistakes (if any),

Answer (score 3):

***1st solution:*** With your shown samples and attempts please try following `awk` code. Written and tested in GNU `awk`.

```bash
awk '
match($0,/(^[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+)(.)([^[:space:]]*.*[[:space:]]+)/,arr){
  print arr[1] arr[2] arr[3] arr[2]
}
' Input_file
```

***2nd solution:*** Using `sed` with its `-E` option to enable ERE here.

```bash
sed -E 's/(^[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+)(.)([^[:space:]]*.*[[:space:]]+).*/\1\2\3\2/'  Input_file
```

Here is the [Online demo](https://regex101.com/r/XqGLcR/1) for shown regex(`(^[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+)(.)([^[:space:]]*.*[[:space:]]+)`) for understanding purposes(NOTE: regex used in site is bit different(to satisfy site's requirement) use regex shown in code here only).

***Bonus solution:*** Adding a `perl` one-liner solution here:

```bash
perl -pe 's/(^[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+)(.)([^[:space:]]*.*[[:space:]]+)[^[:space:]]+$/\1\2\3\2/' Input_file
```

Comment: Thanks! Both of these solutions seem to work on most of the lines, but not all. They do delete the last column, and for most, the first character replaces it. I notice than when my third column is just one letter, for example C, or N, or O, there last column is blank. I will post another comment with an example line for those where it does not work. Because it is a comment, the spacing will be incorrect. I still need the spacing to be as shown. Thanks!!!

Comment: ATOM   1488  O   LIG X  52       5.636 -11.834  10.151  1.00  0.00      LIGA

Comment: @user19619903, ok I have edited my answer now, it should work now for single letter in 3rd column as well, let me know how it goes.

Comment: Thank you for tour help! The first two solution work at adding the new column made by the first character of the third column, but it does not delete the 11th (LIGA) column. I am afraid that if I delete it, I will mess up the spacing again.

Comment: @user19619903, could you please give me example on same and I could help more here 

Answer (score 3):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -E 's/(([^ ]* ){2})(([[:alpha:]]).* ).*/\1\3\4/' input_file
ATOM     55  CE1 LIG X   1      -2.921   4.159 -10.046  1.00  0.00      C
```

Using GNU `sed` to retain spacing within a loop

```
$ sed -E ':a;s/(([^ ]* +){11})[A-Z]/\1 /;ta;s/(([^ ]*( )+){2}([[:alpha:]]).*)/\1\3\4/' input_file
ATOM     55  CE1 LIG X   1      -2.921   4.159 -10.046  1.00  0.00           C
```

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -ape '$lc = substr $F[2],0,1; s/$F[11]/   $lc/' original.pdb
```

- Use `-a` to autosplit into `@F`
- Use `-p` to loop, `-e` to execute inline program
- `$lc = substr $F[2],0,1` - get first char of 3rd col as variable `$lc`
- `s/$F[11]/   $lc/` - replace 12th column with 3 spaces then `$lc`

This should get you close.  I can't exactly follow the column counts and space counts.

But it's just counting on the 12th col being a unique string, that can be replaced with    `$lc`

This also depends on 12th column 'LIGA' always being 4 chars. If that field is variable width, you could always replace all the chars in it with a space, and then replace the last char:

```
perl -ape '$lc = substr $F[2],0,1; ($new = $F[11]) =~ s/./ /g; $new =~ s/.$/$lc/; s/$F[11]/$new/' original.pdb
```

... again, `$F[11]` must be a unique string, or any other earlier occurrence will be replaced.   But depending on that means you keep the char spacing of the original.

Comment: Thank you! This is very close to what I need. The 'LIGA' column is indeed always 4 chars. Your answer helped me a lot. The spacing between the 11th column (the 0.00 column) and the newly created column with the first character in the 3rd column, is 9 when I use your solution. This should be 11. Is this something that can be changed from the solution line? I am still very new at using awk! Thanks

Comment: I was able to fix the spacing from your explanation! Thank you so much! This was very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

It is simpler using this `gnu-awk` solution with `gensub`:

```bash
awk '{
$0 = gensub(/^(\s*\S+(\s+\S+)+)\s+\S+\s*$/, "\\1" sprintf("%12s", substr($3,1,1)), "1")
} 1' file

ATOM     55  CE1 LIG X   1      -2.921   4.159 -10.046  1.00  0.00           C
```

Comment: Thanks! The spacing is not right though. I need the spacing between the 11th and 12th columns should be 11, not 6. Is this something that can be fixed from this line of code? Thanks!

Comment: You mean you always want to have `11` spaces between 11th and 12th columns even if it is not there in original input?

Comment: Can you try my updated answer now that makes sure to always insert `11` spaces before last column.

Answer (score 1):

With `gnu awk` you can split on the field separator and keep track of the separators.

Then set the last column to the first character of column 3, and set the separator for the last item to 11 spaces.

```
awk '{
  nr = split($0, a, FS, seps)
  if (nr > 4) {
    a[nr] = substr(a[3],1,1)
    seps[nr-1] = "           "
    for (i = 1; i <= nr; ++i) {
      printf "%s%s", a[i], seps[i]
    }
    printf "\n"
    next
  }
}1' file
```

If the contents of the file is:

```
ATOM     55  CE1 LIG X   1      -2.921   4.159 -10.046  1.00  0.00      LIGA
ATOM     55  CE1 LIG X
ATOM     55  CE1 LIG
ATOM     55  CE1
ATOM     55
ATOM
```

Output:

```
ATOM     55  CE1 LIG X   1      -2.921   4.159 -10.046  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     55  CE1 LIG           C
ATOM     55  CE1 LIG
ATOM     55  CE1
ATOM     55
ATOM
```

Answer (score 1):

Using any POSIX awk no matter which char(s) are in the 3rd and/or last fields:

a) maintaining the spacing as you said you wanted in the subject line:

```
$ awk '{sub(/[^[:space:]]+$/,""); print $0 substr($3,1,1)}' file
ATOM     55  CE1 LIG X   1      -2.921   4.159 -10.046  1.00  0.00      C
```

b) or changing the spacing between the last 2 fields to 11 chars as you show in your example:

```
$ awk '{sub(/[[:space:]]+[^[:space:]]+$/,""); printf "%s%12s\n", $0, substr($3,1,1)}' file
ATOM     55  CE1 LIG X   1      -2.921   4.159 -10.046  1.00  0.00           C
```

Answer (score 0):

here's a more generic `awk` solution without needing `gawk`'s custom features :

```
ATOM     55  CE1 LIG X   1      -2.921   4.159 -10.046  1.00  0.00      LIGA
ATOM     55  CE1 LIG X
ATOM     55  CE1 LIG
ATOM     55  CE1
ATOM     55
ATOM
```

> ```
> mawk 'BEGIN { _____=_=(_=(_=(_=" ")_)(_)_)_
>
>          FS = "^"(_="[[:space:]]+")"|"(_)"$" (OFS="")
>         __ = index(_,"s")
>                           sub("[[]:.+$",    "^&"_, _)
>      ___ = substr((_)_, index(____="^"((_)_)".", "+"),
>                        length(_) )  "$"
>      __ = _ (_ = "")
>      _+= _+=_ = sub(".",_,____) 
>
>  } { NF=NF } gsub(__,"&")<_ || match($!_, ____) + \
>               sub(___,(_____) substr($!_, RLENGTH,-_<_))'
> ```

```
ATOM     55  CE1 LIG X   1      -2.921   4.159 -10.046  1.00  0.00            C
ATOM     55  CE1 LIG            C
ATOM     55  CE1 LIG
ATOM     55  CE1
ATOM     55
ATOM
```